# Javascript - load an image before the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a website and have an image as the header, but when I load the page it will jump half way down the page, load the image and then jump back up.  How can I make the image load in first to prevent it from jumping?

HTML:

```
<div class="refocus" id="hero-header">
  <div class="refocus-img-bg"></div>
  <div class="refocus-img focus-in">
    HTML: 
  </div>
  <div class="refocus-text-container">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=".col-md-6">
                <div id="section1">
                    <div id = "sub-text">
                        <h1>Hello</h1>
                        <br>
                        <h2>Hello</h2>
                        <h3><br>Hello.</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="image">
                        <img src="images/aboutme.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="buttoncontainer">
                    <div id="totimeline"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-large">&#x25BC;</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60z6amd3/3/) to replicate this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things for this.

1) Set the dimensions of your image inline. This is actually a recommended method of preventing the very thing you are experiencing where the page jumps around after images load in. By setting the dimensions inline, the browser will already know how tall the image needs to be and will reserve the space for it before it even finishes loading in.

Example:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="150" width="350">
```

2) If you don't prefer to set the dimensions inline, it seems you could also just set the height in your styles ahead of time and that would do the trick as well.

Example:

```
.refocus-img{
    height:150px;
}
```